# Opencv vs Opengl for image filters

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing, opengl-es, imagefilter

I'm a complete beginner in image processing thing so please do excuse me if my question is foolish .Basically I'm trying to develope an image filter app .So, when I googled I came to know that both `openCV` and `openGL` can be used for this purpose .

But I'm not sure which language would be the best means by speed or efficiency ?

Can anyone please enlighten me about this topic a bit?

Comment: " Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it. "

Comment: @SilverMonkey thanks for your suggestion sir but I'm a complete beginner I need help for what to read that's why I've asked the question

Comment: @SilverMonkey you shouldn't forget at some point you're also a beginner so please do help the beginners by suggesting relevant things

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**OpenGL**](https://www.opengl.org/) stands for Open *Graphics Library*. It is a 3D graphic rendering library.

[**OpenCV**](https://opencv.org/) stands for Open *Computer Vision*. It is a computer vision library dealing with on real-time image processing.

If you want to create 3D images, you use **OpenGL**. If you want to make the computer understand the imagery, you use **OpenCV**.

Regarding your usecase, ie image filtering, OpenCV is the best for you.

Comment: I do not agree with you. Efficient image filters require GPU involvement, opencv was not originally developed with GPU support in mind, and although now GPU support has been added, it is a very well known fact that it is not very stable, not very efficient, does not support every hardware and is generally very painful to deal with. On the other hand, OpenGL is purely GPU-centric, is supported by almost every hardware and OS (including native support for Android), is relatively easy to use, and is ideal for most image filters (due to the fact that most image filters is convolutional).